# setup NSIS build in Bamboo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, build, nsis, bamboo

I have to setup build process in Bamboo server. My requirements are,

1. We have a web-server application [more than 20 web projects, 10 windows service projects, DB scripts, some supported utilities like exe, xml's, code signing certificates, ssl certificates]
2. We have already build automation in c#, which uses NSIS scripts to generate installer.exe

Our build process has the following steps:

> 1. Checkout the source code
> 2. Checkout the Utilities
> 3. Checkout the NSIS installer source code
> 4. Update the source code
> 5. Update the Utilities
> 6. Update the Product versions in all the Assembly files of all the projects & Wix files
> 7. Build all the MSI projects based from the list [Project.xml] -> Once build completed with Code Signing post build CMD, then move to
>      some [ex: LatestPackage] folder in any [ex: Package] directory
> 8. Build all the Web app projects from the list [Project.xml] -> Publish into some [ex: LatestPackage] folder in any [ex: Package]
>      directory
> 9. Build all the support projects for installer from the list [Project.xml]
> 10. Copy the "LatestPackage" from "Package" directory to "LatestPackage" folder in "NSIS Installer" directory
> 11. Update the Installer source codes
> 12. Copy the installer custom assets to respective folder in "Installer" directory [SQL, some exe's]
> 13. Update Installer.xml file with the Branding information's in "Installer" directory
> 14. Compile Installer.nsi file & Installer package will be generated under Installer directory

Could anyone guide me in right path to achieve this.
1. Need to setup task for each and every projects?
2. Where to keep the files once build completed?
3. How to move the all the projects binaries into another projects directory?
4. How to keep the supported files and copy them to our source code folders?
5. How to maintain the generated build?

Answer (score -1):

Is Bamboo Server Windows based? Can Visual Studio be installed on it?

If yes then you can automate building NSIS installers using MSBuild and Visual & Installer.

Also (if VS is present) there is an option to create NSIS project in Visual Studio and build the installer from it (building the solution from command line).

Comment: yes bamboo - window based server here. there is no VS in our bamboo server..

Comment: Ok, this was just my idea to use Visual Studio for this purpose, in that case everything can be automated using Visual Studio pre-build and post-build events for NSIS project (installer). But we cannot write whole code/script for you (as it is almost impossible without further info). Split the question into several separate tasks, show your current scripts and the users will help you with specific questions (I can help with NSIS part).

Comment: as you mentioned i have created MSBuild script for entire build process. Thanks for your inputs